# Finding Contacts that have, and do not have file attachments

Tags: soql

Completely new to SOQL (but not SQL).
Using Developer Console I have two aims:

1. I want a SOQL query to list Contact records that have at least 1 file attached to them.
2. I want a SOQL query to list Contact records that have NO files attached to them.

My aims are relative straight forward on the face of it, but I cannot find a way using SOQL to achieve what I want. The ContentDocument tables seem difficult to work with.

Used the following query (after discovering 'Query All Files' permission) to get all ContentDocuments related to contacts.

```
SELECT 
ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.FileExtension
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact)
```

What I would like to be able to do though is see Contact fields (e.g. Name) and filter on them, but I cannot find a supported way to join Contact with the ContentDocumentLink table.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. So, what did you try? You'll need to use the `ContentDocumentLink` object as part of the query

Comment: Semi-joins and anti-joins (documented as part of [Comparison Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)) are the usual way to handle this. `ContentDocumentLink`, however, can't be used in semi/anti joins. You'll still need to query `ContentDocumentLink` to do this, the main point to note is that neither of your two scenarios is possible with a single query.

Comment: @cropredy I have added more detail to my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, what you want is

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact
         WHERE Id IN (SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink)
```

but ContentDocumentLink has restrictions when used in queries

```
Entity 'ContentDocumentLink' is not supported for semi join inner selects
```

This is covered in the [ContentDocumentLink Object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm?q=ContentDocumentLink)

> You can't run a query without filters against ContentDocumentLink.
>
> You can't filter on ContentDocument fields if you're filtering by ContentDocumentId. You can only filter on ContentDocument fields if you're filtering by LinkedEntityId.
>
> You can't filter on the related object fields. For example, you can't filter on the properties of the account to which a file is linked. You can filter on the properties of the file, such as the title field.
>
> A SOQL query must filter on one of Id, ContentDocumentId, or LinkedEntityId.

This leaves you with the following:

```
for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, Name, 
                     (SELECT Id, ContentDocument.Title 
                        FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
                   FROM Contact] ) {
     System.debug(c.Name + ' has ' + c.ContentDocumentLinks.size() + ' files');
}
```

***Notes***

1. Exercise for you to build separate lists of Contacts w/ and w/o files
2. Depending on how many Contacts you have in your org, you may need to run this as a batch class (> 50,000 Contacts) or in async (< 50,000 Contacts but more CPU time needed).  Of course, if you can filter the Contacts by date or recordType aforehand, the problem is more tractable

If you think you have lots of Contacts with few associated files

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();

Set<Id> contentDocumentIds = new Map<Id,ContentDocument> ( // get all files
                                   [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument]).keySet();
for (ContentDocumentLink cdl: [SELECT LinkedEntityId // all file CDLs
                                FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds]) {
   if (cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Contact.SObjectType) {
       contactIds.add(cdl.LinkedEntityIds);
   }
}

System.debug('these contacts have files:\n' + [SELECT Id, Name 
               FROM Contact 
               WHERE Id IN :contactIds]); 

System.debug('these contacts have no files:\n' +
               [SELECT Id, Name
                  FROM Contact 
                  WHERE Id NOT IN : contactIds]);
```